# Search mongodb array field and get results on match frequency

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have a mongoDb document in a collection in given format.

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
   "data_id" : 111,
   "names" : ["data1","data2","data3","data4", ----  n size]
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
   "data_id" : 112,
   "names" : ["data1","data2","data7","data8", ----  n size]
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
   "data_id" : 113,
   "names" : ["data1","data9","data10","data11", ----  n size]
}
```

I want to write a query in which i should provide an array of words, say  ["data1","data2","data11"] and it should give me all documents having words from the provided arguments but it should maintain order of results in accordance with maximum words found i.e the document having maximum words from the argument should appear on top.

Kindly also suggest me the way with which i could make this query run faster.

I will be using this query from django backend.

My django model is something like this.

```
  class Data(models.Model):
      data_id = models.IntegerField(required=True)
      names = ListField()
```

Comment: Here is a request in JavaScript that can do the job:
    `var array = ["data1", "data2", "data3"];
    db.data.aggregate([{$match: {names: {$in: array}}},
                       {$project: {_id: 1, data_id: 1, names: 1, wordsFound: {$setIntersection: [array, "$names"]}}},
                       {$project: {_id: 1, data_id: 1, names: 1, wordsFound: {$size: "$wordsFound"}}},
                       {$sort: {wordsFound: -1}},
                       {$project: {_id: 1, data_id: 1, names: 1}}]);`
Just translate it to Python. Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, I am getting strange error, its saying exception: invalid operator '$setIntersection'. Kindly suggest.

Comment: What version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

Comment: Hi, I updated my mongo, now using using version 3.2.9. Its working fine now. Thanks a ton.